# How do I fix a broken dag that requires python provider modules?

Tags: kubernetes, airflow, google-cloud-pubsub, airflow-2.x

Some context: I have a GKE cluster running airflow 2.6.2. Python version 3.7

The direct error im getting is:

```
Broken DAG: [/opt/airflow/dags/repo/airflow/dags/main.py] Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/opt/airflow/dags/repo/airflow/dags/main.py", line 8, in <module>
    from airflow.providers.google.cloud.sensors.pubsub import PubSubPullSensor, PubSubPullOperator
ImportError: cannot import name 'PubSubPullOperator' from 'airflow.providers.google.cloud.sensors.pubsub' (/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/providers/google/cloud/sensors/pubsub.py)
```

I'm trying to use PubSub sensors and operators to trigger a DAG.

However, the error shows to me that for whatever reason airflow is not pulling the right python module from the provider.

Has anyone gotten the PubSub sensors and operators to work? What was your set up to get these modules?

I have tried to ssh in to each of the workers, scheduler, webserver and run `pip install apache-airflow-providers-google` manually to install it but when I did that it already showed that the requirements were satisfied making me more confused because it can't find the module.

Answer (score 0):

go to your composer environment and then navigate to PyPI Packages and provide the packages you want to install.

[image]

Comment: i'm not using composer, I used GKE but installed airflow with helm so managing it myself. Although Im thinking maybe I should do this